# Reading in file gives empty rows and columns

Tags: r, csv

Given this CSV file:

[image: Screenshot of the .csv file when opened in text editor.]

How to read a file so that the extra commas that are not a part of data are excluded?

Comment: Are you able to upload the file or paste the first few rows at least? That would be helpful so we could work with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the file is ok. Have you tried the correct options for arguments in your importing function?
Would you like to try read_delim() from the readr package?